# Kendo chart export to pdf or png

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have a kendo chart with the remote data. Is it possible to export the chart to png or pdf format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if you use some third-party tool such as [InkScape](http://inkscape.org/). The latter can convert SVG (the Kendo UI Chart native format) to pretty much anything else including PNG and PDF. You can use the [svg](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#svg) method of the chart to get the underlying SVG and then send it to a remote service.

Here is an ASP.NET MVC application which shows how: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/tree/master/chart-inkscape-export

Answer (score 4):

Since [Atanas Korchev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14831525/315493), kendo has implemented a built-in method to export a chart as a png, svg or a pdf file.

If you want to export a png file you can do it by using the [exportImage function](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#methods-exportImage):

```
kendoChart.exportImage().done(function(data) {
    kendo.saveAs({
        dataURI: data,
        fileName: "chart.png"
    });
});
```

For a PDF, it's almost the same logic with the [exportPDF function](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#methods-exportPDF):

```
chart.exportPDF({ paperSize: "Auto", landscape: true }).done(function(data) {
    kendo.saveAs({
        dataURI: data,
        fileName: "chart.pdf"
    });
});
```

You may refer to [kendo chart API documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart) for more details about those functions.